# Decomposition by subtraction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

In how many ways one can decompose an integer $n$ to smaller integers at least 3? for example 13 has the following decompositions:

\begin{gather*}
13\\
3,10\\
4,9\\
5,8\\
6,7\\
3,3,7\\
3,4,6\\
3,5,5\\
3,3,3,4\\
4,4,5\\
\end{gather*}

Points and hints are welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason you have not yet accepted an answer? I believe the question you raised has been answered in full. This also goes for the other [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33315/9436) you raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let there be $p(n)$ partitions of the positive integer $n$ that use integers $1, 2, \dots, n$ ([A000041](http://oeis.org/A000041)).

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of partitions that don't use the numbers $1$ and $2$ is given by:

$$p(n) - p(n - 1) - p(n - 2) + p(n - 3)$$

since, there are $p(n-1)$ numbers that use $1$ in the partition of $n$, $p(n-2)$ that use $2$, and there are $p(n-3)$ that use both $1$ and $2$ in the partition of $n$.

In your case, the answer is $p(13)-p(12)-p(11)+p(10)=101-77-56+42=10$ (counting the trivial partition $13=13$).

Comment: Both comments were extremely helpful. Now, is there any idea about how I can count those decompositions with exactly $i$ members? for example there are $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ decompositions for $n$ with exactly two members, for 13 we have $\{10,3\}$,$\{9,4\}$,.... What about the number of decompositions of $n$ with exactly $i$ members, members are greater than two?   
It is clear that because the members are at least three, $i$ is smaller than $\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor$.

Comment: You can pull off a kind of recursion similar to the one @DerekJennings mentions in his answer below, by adjoining one more variable to the recursive formula to keep track of the number of addends that you've used so far. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33315/partition-an-integer-n-by-limitation-on-size-of-the-partition/33411#33411).

Answer (score 4):

This is usually called "partitions of $n$ into parts of at least 3"

You will find much of what you want in [OEIS A008483](http://oeis.org/A008483).  There are some differences: with your example of partitions of 13, the single part $13$ is usually regarded as meeting the condition, and you have also missed $4+4+5$, while the partition $3+6+4$ is seen as being equivalent to $3+4+6$.   So the OEIS has 10 possible partitions of 13 with each parts at least 3.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(k,n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into parts at least as large as $k$ then

$$p(k,n) = p(k,n-k) + p(k+1,n)$$

as per [Partition (Number Theory).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

And so

$$ p(k+1,n) = p(k,n) - p(k,n-k).$$

Therefore

$$ \begin{align}
p(3,n) &= p(2,n) - p(2,n-2) \\
&= \{ p(1,n) - p(1,n-1) \} - \{ p(1,n-2) - p(1,n-3) \} \\
&= p(n) - p(n-1) - p(n-2) + p(n-3),
\end{align} $$

where $p(n)$ is the usual partition function, as per quantumelixir's formula.